# Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, если перед сказуемым есть частица "не"

Tags: пунктуация, тире, сказуемые, подлежащее, авторская-пунктуация

*Начнём с того, что создавать резюме на сайтах AA и BB и откликаться там на вакансии работодателей (—) не лучшая идея.*

По правилам, если перед сказуемым есть частица "не", тире не ставится, но при таком объёмном подлежащем хочется поставить тире для выделения сказуемого. Возможно поставить тире как авторский знак?

Comment: "Откликаться на вакансии", "вакансии работодателей" — скорее всего, это речевые ошибки.

Comment: Да ведь они — для мебели.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнём с того, что **создавать** резюме на сайтах AA и BB **и откликаться** там на вакансии работодателей — **не лучшая идея.**

Тире при наличии отрицания не ставится в общем случае, но может ставиться  для интонационного членения предложения. Также следует отметить, что если главные члены выражены инфинитивом, то тире ставится и при наличии частицы НЕ, то есть этот случай требует паузы для понимания структуры предложения.

Также **распространенность** главных членов способствует постановке тире и  при наличии отрицания с той же целью — правильно определить состав подлежащего и сказуемого.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Тире не  ставится: 3) если перед сказуемым стоит отрицание не: Офицер этот не чета вам (Фед.); …Уссурийский тигр совсем не сказка, явь почти (Март.); Бедность не порок (Погов.); Сердце не камень (Погов.); Аналогия не доказательство.

**Постановка тире в этом случае имеет целью логически и интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое:** **Но объяснение — не оправдание** (М. Г.); Его взгляды на семейный этикет — не предрассудок ли это?

Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если оба они выражены неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом) или если один из главных членов выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — неопределенной формой глагола: **Чай пить — не дрова рубить. (Посл.)**